# How to deploy Spring 4 web application in Wildfly 8.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I am developing a spring 4 based web applciation, that is divided into two modules; one the service (jar) and the other is the web application. The web war will contain the service jar and other library dependencies within it. The application works as expected when deployed with the Spring tool suite vFabric tc Server. But when the same war is deployed in the Wildfly 8.1, though the application allows to login, on every web page of the app, the validator recieves the `target` with all the form values empty. Why is that?

> ```
>  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)
> ```

I have the jboss-deployment-structure.xml like the one below

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="org.slf4j"/>
       </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Do I need to configure any more information in this?
I tried to deploy the war by directly copying into the  `wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments`. Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the management interface and deploy from there.

Go to yourhost:9990, login and deploy.

Or you can copy to the deployment folder but then you need to create a .dodeploy file to trigger the actual deployment. I don't use the file approach very often but you can find more information here

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Application+deployment

Comment: I deployed the war from the web management console, the war deploys, I enabled it. I could login into the application. I navigate to a page in the application, enter values and submit, the validator class for that page receives the bean-object, but the form fields empty/null. Why is it? Do I need to do any special configuration for web-app developed in spring-4?

Comment: If you deployed and can navigate through the application, job is done. There is no special setups for JBoss/Wildfly to run a Spring 4 web application. I can't tell you why the fields are coming null without looking at your code. But in this case, I think it's another matter.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the same application I tried with Widfly 9 and it works. Why is that?

Comment: Well, as I said, your question was about deploying to Wildfly and you got it deployed to wildfly. I can't not help you with your app without seeing your code. I could be a dependency that is in verion 9 but not in version 8.1? I don't know.

Comment: I will edit this question. I found the problem was with the Multipart resolver. The StandardServletMultipartResolver didnt work in the Wildfly 8.1 and I tried with the CommonsMultipartResolver, and it worked! But, the same didnt work in the Wildfly9. Why is this?
>>>>
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
 public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
  StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
  CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  return commonsMultipartResolver;
  // return multipartResolver;
 }

Comment: Well, that is easy, version incompatibility. There is always someone to fix problems like this when the company refresh technology stacks. I do believe that if that is another problem, you should ask another question. This a Q&A site which means that someone will come to this question looking for a solution for wildfly deployment problems.